# Integration of complex exponential function over $\mathbb C$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, exponential-function, complex-integration

Find the limit $$\lim_{z \to \infty}\int_{\mathbb C}|w|e^{-|z-w|^2}dA(w) $$

where A is area measure such that dA=rdrd$\theta$

Please help me, I did four page computation by changing to polar cordinates and using modified Bessel formula. My computation shows limit does not exists but I am not about limit. This integration is identical to integration I asked some time ago.
This is part of my research so please help me.

Comment: Is $z$ real and tends to $+\infty$?

Comment: No, z is complex

Comment: Forgetting the limit in $z$ for the moment, why should the integral even converge? The integrand is growing exponentially.

Comment: I am sorry, I edited now

Comment: The limit is $\infty$. Do a change of variables $v = z-w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit is $+\infty$. You can see this either by making the change of variables $w\mapsto z-w$ in the integral (as PhoemueX commented), or by the simple inequality
$$
\int_{\Bbb C} |w|e^{-|z-w|^2} dA(w) \ge \int_{\{w\colon |z-w|\le 1\}} |w|e^{-|z-w|^2} dA(w) \ge e^{-1}(|z|-1) \int_{\{w\colon |z-w|\le 1\}} dA(w) = \frac{\pi(|z|-1)}e.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!! @Greg Martin, is it possible to find integral explicitly?